# File not created using Log4Net

Tags: log4net

I do not know why my log file is not created . Here is my config entries for Log4Net

```
 <log4Net>

<root>
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
</root>
   <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newlineExtra Info: %property{testProperty}%newline%exception"/>
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="INFO"/>
    <levelMax value="FATAL"/>
  </filter>
</appender>

<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="log.txt"/>
  <param name="appendToFile" value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="true"/>

  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newlineExtra%newline%exception"/>
  </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="Log4NetTest.OtherClass">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
</logger>
```

Then at my application startup I take care to run the follwoing line :

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

And having the following at the declare section of each of my classes :

```
//use for logging information
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(
        System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

Then when using

```
log.Fatal("Fatal : Startup start")
```

it should create a log entry in the outpout directory of my project ! But not file exist

What did I do wrong in here ?

regards
serge

Comment: Are you seeing anything in console output from logging? For the file output you typically want to be explicit about the folder rather than just specifying a file name and you need to ensure sufficient file writing permissions are set

Comment: Args find out. Case sensitive in Log4net entriy

Comment: To help others, why not post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact what I do wrong is that I get a section definition as log4**N**et and in the section itself it was define as .

This prevent logging information

regards
serge